# Yii2 mongodb ActiveRecord always returns null since yum update, while direct query works

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I've updated my `CentOS` machine yesterday (which included php 5.6.5 and php-pecl-mongo 1.6.0.1). 
Since then yii2-mongodb cannot find records anymore.

Spent the entire morning testing and trying to figure it out and it comes down to this:

Every call I do directly to `mongodb` works. Since I'm using the collection handle obtained through `Yii`, I know the `ActiveRecord` classes have valid handles to `mongodb` as well. Anything going over the `ActiveQuery` / `ActiveRecord` implementation fails. I cannot figure out why.

I've assembled some test scenario's based on a dummy class that tries to eliminate as much overhead as possible:

```
class Test extends \yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function collectionName() { return 'PostContent'; }
    public function attributes() { return ['_id', 'postId', 'text', 'title', 'renderedText', 'renderedAt']; }
}
$condition = ['postId' => 5336265];

echo 'Direct:';
var_dump(Test::getDb()->getCollection('PostContent')->mongoCollection->findOne($condition));

echo 'Direct 2: ';
var_dump(Test::getCollection()->mongoCollection->findOne($condition));

echo 'Cursor:';
$cursor = Test::getDb()->getCollection('PostContent')->mongoCollection->find($condition, []);
var_dump($cursor->next());

echo 'ActiveQuery:';
var_dump(Test::find()->where($condition)->asArray()->one());

echo 'findOne:';
var_dump(Test::findOne($condition));
```

The output is (cropped the actual results as they don't matter):

```
Direct:
<snip - correct result>

Direct2:
<snip - correct result>

Cursor:
<snip - correct result>

ActiveQuery:
null

findOne:
<crash> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (../yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php:1046)
```

The last crash is because the `null`-result actually makes it through the check and the `populateRecord` function is called which tries to `foreach` on the `null` value.

Any help is really appreciated, I don't know what to try anymore and I have a site with a lot of daily visits that is currently broken.

Edit: 
I just downgraded the mongo driver from `1.6.0-1` back to `1.5.8-1` and **everything works again**. So there is either a problem in the new `mongodb` php driver release or in the way `Yii2` talks to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug with the cursor functionality in `MongoDB` and 1.6.1 is being prepared for release. Please refer to [this bug ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-1382) for more information.

So once more: **do *not* upgrade to `php-pecl-mongo-1.6.0-1`**